# Random images on 'refresh' in HTML without JavaScript

Tags: html

I once saw in a tutorial video about an HTML line of code that generates random images that it fetches from the internet and puts into the webpage, I remember it being a normal img tag but inside the ref attribute contained a link that now I don't remember what it was.
Searched about this in Google but all I could find was about  loading images from the directory or using the help of Javascript.

Comment: Are you looking for placeholder images?

Comment: No, just an image in the body tag. I remember something like mentioning number  like 200 (dimension) along with the ref attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by delegating the randomness to the server that serves the images.  Consider the service provided by [PlaceIMG](https://placeimg.com/).  Setting any `<img/>` tag to one of their URLs will let your show a "random" image.  What is actually happening is that the backend gets a request for an image and serves any image it wants.

You can do this with your own, self-hosted image server and in basically any server-side language and without client-side JavaScript.  However, there has to be logic *somewhere* to do the randomness:

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many sites that serve as random image source, for example https://picsum.photos.

**Working example** (refresh to see the effect):

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
```